# Как правильно заменить местозаполнители в запросе?

Tags: python

Логика скрипта состоит в том, чтобы в метод передавался запрос (*query*) и неограниченный кортеж `values`.

После, метод перебирает кортеж `values` (сохраняет в переменную), находит все индексы символа `?` и вставляет значения кортежа `values` в список под индексом символа '?'.

Вот код, но он заменяет лишь почему-то на последнее значение:

```
def test(query, *values):
        print(f"Query: {query}\nValues: {values}")
        query_list = list(query)
        indexes = {}

        for count, value in enumerate(query_list):
            if value == '?':
                print(f"\n[*] Знак '?' найден в списке под индексом {count}")  
                for i in range(len(values)):
                    print(f"Index of value: [{i}], Index of symbol: {count}")
                    indexes[count] = values[i]

        for key, value in indexes.items():
            query_list[key] = value

        query = "".join(query_list)

        print(f"Result: {query}\nDict: {indexes}")
```

Вывод:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM `?` WHERE `password` = ? AND `login` = ?
Values: ('users', 'qwerty', 'Alex2007')

[*] Знак '?' найден в списке под индексом 15
Index of value: [0], Index of symbol: 15
Index of value: [1], Index of symbol: 15
Index of value: [2], Index of symbol: 15

[*] Знак '?' найден в списке под индексом 37
Index of value: [0], Index of symbol: 37
Index of value: [1], Index of symbol: 37
Index of value: [2], Index of symbol: 37

[*] Знак '?' найден в списке под индексом 53
Index of value: [0], Index of symbol: 53
Index of value: [1], Index of symbol: 53
Index of value: [2], Index of symbol: 53
Result: SELECT * FROM `Alex2007` WHERE `password` = Alex2007 AND `login` = Alex2007
Dict: {15: 'Alex2007', 37: 'Alex2007', 53: 'Alex2007'}
```

Comment: `indexes[count] = values[i]`  исполняется каждый раз по три раза и каждый раз перезаписывает предыдущее значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте изменить код так:

```
values = iter(values)
for count, value in enumerate(query_list):
   if value == '?':
        print(f"\n[*] Знак '?' найден в списке под индексом {count}")  
        v = next(values)
        print(f"Value: [{v}], Index of symbol: {count}")
        indexes[count] = v
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Не понял как с кортежами работать, сейчас, благодаря вам понимаю

Answer (score 7):

У вас неправильный и опасный подход. Таким образом вы открываетесь для [SQL Injections](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/sql-injection-sqli/).

Правильным подходом здесь будет использование связываемых переменных (синонимы: `prepared statement`, `bind variables`). Связать можно только литералы, но не наименования таблиц или столбцов. Поэтому вашу задачу придется разделить на две части - динамическое формирование запроса с подставлением названий таблиц / столбцов и на безопасное связывание переменных:

```
qry_template = """SELECT * FROM {} WHERE password = ? AND login = ?"""
```

пользоваться этим нужно так:

```
cursor.execute(qry_template.format(table_name), values) # здесь значения переменных `password` и `login` автоматически свяжутся со значениями из списка или кортежа `values` 
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    ...
```

---

можно также использовать `f-string`, но интерполяция переменной будет происходить в момент создания / объявления переменной `qry`:

```
table_name = "my_table_name"
qry = f"""SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE password = ? AND login = ?"""
....
cursor.execute(qry, values)
```

Comment: А можно использовать новые f-строки?

Comment: @KLEYZYツ, конечно можно, но у них один маленький недостаток - интерполяция (подставление значения) делается в момент создания строки. С форматом этот момент можно отложить на потом...

Comment: то есть как я понимаю, можно использовать обычные f-строки с дополнительным аргументом в методе execute?

Comment: @KLEYZYツ, насколько мне известно в самом `ANSI SQL Standard` понятие `placeholders` отсутствует. Этот функционал реализуется в драйверах, которые обеспечивают коммуникацию между вашей программой и БД. Скорее всего поэтому в различных Python драйверах для разных баз данных используются [различные стили `placeholders`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

Comment: понятно! Спасибо вам огромное! Можете, пожалуйста подсказать как проверить мою программу на SQL инъекции?

Comment: @KLEYZYツ, это врядли получится сделать в рамках комментария к ответу. PS используйте подход, который я показал в ответе и шанс того, что ваш код будет подвержен SQL Injections будет минимальным)

Comment: поменял код на ваш и получилось вот так: https://pastebin.com/6XUgs7Yv, но получается ошибка: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @KLEYZYツ, я думаю в вашем случае надо делать так: `cursor.execute(query, *values)` - если вы передаете `values` как позиционные аргументы

Comment: нет, я делаю так:
def test(self, query, *values):
    pass
то есть *values может быть неограниченное количество

Comment: @KLEYZYツ, для того, чтобы `cursor.execute(query, params)` отработал правильно число значений в списке/кортеже `params` должно строго соответствовать числу связываемых параметров (`?`) в запросе.

Comment: оно совпадает, exec_ = connection.exec("SELECT * FROM `?`", 'users')

Comment: @RomanKonoval, в качестве связываемых переменных можно указывать литералы. Имена таблиц и столбцов нельзя параметризировать - я об этом написал в ответе

Comment: Да, точно, это я не обратил внимание, что тут имя таблицы подставляется. Я о другой частой проблеме тут подумал, когда вместо последовательности из одного элемента передают сам элемент. А связываемые переменные, действительно, допускаются только там где по синтаксису sql допускается выражение. Т.е. для таблиц, столбцов а еще ключевых слов типа select и from - нельзя.