# Как создать postgreSQL на основе json?

Tags: python, postgresql

пытаюсь добавить данные из json в postgreSQL, выдаёт такую ошибку. В чём может быть дело, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 95, in run
    result = self.view_func(request, **values)
  File "/Users/abra/Desktop/WorkAndArt/abra/abra/ServerFF/FFServer/FFServer/urls.py", line 102, in createDataBase
    cur.execute(sql_string)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 2: ...437\u043e\u0442\u0438\u043a, 120 \u043c\u043b.)', [{'value':...
```

Код:

```
@api.get("/createDataBase")
def createDataBase(request):
    with open('/Users/abra/Desktop/WorkAndArt/abra/abra/ServerFF/FFServer/FFServer/FFArchive.json') as json_data:
        productJson = json.load(json_data)
        # use JSON loads to create a list of records
# create a nested list of the records' values
        values = [list(x.values()) for x in productJson]

# get the column names
        columns = [list(x.keys()) for x in productJson][0]
        
# value string for the SQL string
        values_str = ""

# enumerate over the records' values
        for i, record in enumerate(values):

            # declare empty list for values
            val_list = []

    # append each value to a new list of values
            for v, val in enumerate(record):
                if type(val) == str:
                    val = str(Json(val)).replace('"', '')
                val_list += [str(val)]

    # put parenthesis around each record string
            values_str += "(" + ', '.join(val_list) + "),\n"

# remove the last comma and end SQL with a semicolon
        values_str = values_str[:-2] + ";"

        # concatenate the SQL string
        table_name = "PRODUCTS"
        sql_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)\nVALUES %s" % (
            table_name,
            ', '.join(columns),
            values_str
        )
        con = psycopg2.connect(
            database="postgres",
            user="abra",
            password="abra",
            host="localhost",
            port="5432"
        )
        print("Database opened successfully")
        
        cur = con.cursor()
        #УДАЛЯЕМ ПРЕДИДУЩИЮ
        cur.execute('''DROP TABLE PRODUCTS''')
        # СОЗДАЁМ ТАБЛИЦУ
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
        (code TEXT NOT NULL,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        details json[],
        articul TEXT NOT NULL,
        price TEXT NOT NULL,
        quantity TEXT NOT NULL,
        stores json[],
        brand json,
        description TEXT NOT NULL,
        image_url json[],
        groups json[],
        certificates TEXT NOT NULL,
        portion TEXT NOT NULL,
        SubjectToCertification boolean NOT NULL
        );''')
        print("Table created successfully")
        cur.execute(sql_string)
        
        return "Server was creates with table: " + str(columns)
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "code": "8308b6d2-d9cc-11e9-802f-001e582bf58c#6ddfd039-1b97-11ea-b8c5-b42e99659391",
        "name": "SHAABOOM PUMP SHOT, 120 мл (Экзотик, 120 мл.)",
        "details": [
            {
                "value": "Экзотик",
                "detail_type": {
                    "name": "Вкус"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "120 мл.",
                "detail_type": {
                    "name": "Упаковка"
                }
            }
        ],
        "articul": "018189",
        "price": 160,
        "quantity": 79,
        "stores": [
            {
                "store": "ТренажерыСпорттовары",
                "quantity": "48"
            },
            {
                "store": "ИП Проспект",
                "quantity": "31"
            }
        ],
        "brand": {
            "name": "Kevin Levrone"
        },
        "description": "Надоело бороться с усталостью на каждой тренировке? Тогда воспользуйтесь инновационным предтренировочным комплексом SHAABOOM PUMP от компании KEVIN LEVRONE. \n Уже с первой порции вы прочувствуете невероятный прилив сил и энергии, который позволит в разы поднять продуктивность тренировок. При регулярном использовании атлеты также отмечают, что предтреник положительно влияет на выносливость, силовые показатели и рост мышечной массы. \n\n<h2>Ингредиенты</h2>\n<div class=\"table-wrapper\">\n<table>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"3\">\n<div class=\"table-wrapper\">\n<table>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>120 мл</td>\n<td colspan=\"2\"> </td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n</div>\n</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"3\">Порция 30 мл</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"3\">Количество порций в ампуле - 4</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"3\"> </td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"2\"><span class=\"strong\">На</span></td>\n<td><span class=\"strong\">120 мл</span></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"2\">Бета-Аланин</td>\n<td>3500 мг</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td colspan=\"2\"",
        "image_url": [
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018189_1.png"
            },
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018189_0.png"
            },
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018189_2.png"
            },
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018189_3.png"
            }
        ],
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "СПОРТИВНОЕ ПИТАНИЕ"
            },
            {
                "name": "Предтренировочные комплексы"
            }
        ],
        "certificates": "",
        "portion": 4,
        "SubjectToCertification": true
    }]
```

sql:

```
column names: ['code', 'name', 'details', 'articul', 'price', 'quantity', 'stores', 'brand', 'description', 'image_url', 'groups', 'certificates', 'portion', 'SubjectToCertification']
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (code, name, details, articul, price, quantity, stores, brand, description, image_url, groups, certificates, portion, SubjectToCertification)
VALUES ('8308b6d2-d9cc-11e9-802f-001e582bf58c#6ddfd039-1b97-11ea-b8c5-b42e99659391', 'SHAABOOM PUMP SHOT, 120 мл (Экзотик, 120 мл.)', [{'value': 'Экзотик', 'detail_type': {'name': 'Вкус'}}, {'value': '120 мл.', 'detail_type': {'name': 'Упаковка'}}], '018189', 160, 79, [{'store': 'ТренажерыСпорттовары', 'quantity': '48'}, {'store': 'ИП Проспект', 'quantity': '31'}], {'name': 'Kevin Levrone'}, 'Надоело бороться с усталостью на каждой тренировке? Тогда воспользуйтесь инновационным предтренировочным комплексом SHAABOOM PUMP от компании KEVIN LEVRONE. 
 Уже с первой порции вы прочувствуете невероятный прилив сил и энергии, который позволит в разы поднять продуктивность тренировок. При регулярном использовании атлеты также отмечают, что предтреник положительно влияет на выносливость, силовые показатели и рост мышечной массы. 

<h2>Ингредиенты</h2>
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>120 мл</td>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Порция 30 мл</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Количество порций в ампуле - 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span class="strong">На</span></td>
<td><span class="strong">120 мл</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Бета-Аланин</td>
<td>3500 мг</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"', [{'osPath': 'productImage/018189_1.png'}, {'osPath': 'productImage/018189_0.png'}, {'osPath': 'productImage/018189_2.png'}, {'osPath': 'productImage/018189_3.png'}], [{'name': 'СПОРТИВНОЕ ПИТАНИЕ'}, {'name': 'Предтренировочные комплексы'}], '', 4, True);
```

Comment: Сделал, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Сейчас у вас проблема в синтаксисе, так как, например, поле в  `details`, очевидно, должна сохраняться строка, но кавычек в генерируемом sql для нее нет. Вместо манипуляций со строками используйте связываемые переменные (bind variables).

Comment: Простите за наглость, но приведите пример, если Вас это не затруднит.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно заменить местозаполнители в запросе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1329683/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5) Вот вам пример и дубликат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вновь всех приветствую! Я нашёл решение своей проблемы, оно настолько просто, что мои танцы с бубном кажутся теперь смешными, надеюсь и многим другим, оно поможет!**

### Что нужно сделать?

Если у Вас присутствуют ключи в json, которые имеют внутренние ключи, с внутренними ключами и тп, и тд, **нужно сделать только одну вещь**.

**Но сначала немного подробностей**

Представим, что у Вас есть подобный json.

```
{
        "code": "16b52f60-d9de-11e9-802f-001e582bf58c#0e2c1b96-1b97-11ea-b8c5-b42e99659391",
        "name": "Scatterbrain Shot, 120 мл (Маракуйя, 120 мл.)",
        "details": [
            {
                "value": "Маракуйя",
                "detail_type": {
                    "name": "Вкус"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "120 мл.",
                "detail_type": {
                    "name": "Упаковка"
                }
            }
        ],
        "articul": "018190",
        "price": 140,
        "quantity": 48,
        "stores": [
            {
                "store": "Склад №3",
                "quantity": "0"
            },
            {
                "store": "Склад №2",
                "quantity": "48"
            }
        ],
        "brand": {
            "name": "Kevin Levrone"
        },
        "description": "Зарядись энергией вместе с Scatterbrain Shot от KEVIN LEVRONE",
        "image_url": [
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018190_0.png"
            },
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018190_1.png"
            },
            {
                "osPath": "productImage/018190_2.png"
            }
        ],
        "groups": [
            {
                "name": "СПОРТИВНОЕ ПИТАНИЕ"
            },
            {
                "name": "Предтренировочные комплексы"
            }
        ],
        "certificates": "123.123123.12312RU",
        "portion": 4,
        "SubjectToCertification": true
    },
```

**Как только я начал рыскать форумы, там предлагались кучи, длинных, сложных, и непонятных вариантов, понять которые, позволит лишь "тотальное" изучение postgreSQL**

***Теперь нам необходимо создать под него таблицу***

```
# СОЗДАЁМ ТАБЛИЦУ
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE PRODUCTS''')
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
      (code TEXT NOT NULL,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        articul TEXT ,
        details json,
        price int ,
        quantity int ,
        stores json,
        brand text ,
        description TEXT ,
        image_url json,
        groups json,
        certificates TEXT ,
        portion text ,
        SubjectToCertification boolean
     );''')
    print("Table created successfully")
```

**Читаем наш json file**

```
if os.path.exists("/Users/Archive.json"):
        with open("/Users/Archive.json", encoding='utf-8') as jsonFile:
            templates = json.load(jsonFile)
            dumpsJson = json.dumps(templates, indent=4)
            loadsJson = json.loads(dumpsJson)
```

**Далее происходит "магия", которая на большинстве форумов, была заключена в 100 строчных скриптах**

```
for obj in loadsJson:
                #Правим для получения SubjectToCertification
                if("SubjectToCertification" in obj):
                    pass
                else:
                    obj["SubjectToCertification"] = False
   
                cur.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (code,name,image_url,articul,details,price,quantity,stores,brand,description,groups,certificates,portion,SubjectToCertification) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s)",(obj["code"],obj["name"],json.dumps(obj["image_url"]),obj["articul"],json.dumps(obj["details"]),obj["price"],obj["quantity"],json.dumps(obj["stores"]),json.dumps(obj["brand"]),obj["description"],json.dumps(obj["groups"]),obj["certificates"],obj["portion"],obj["SubjectToCertification"])
                )
```

*Немного объясню*

1. %s должно быть аналогично количеству ключей.
2. Если ключ, который мы передаём имеет type == dict делаем следующее

   json.dumps(obj["ключ"]

### И ВУАЛЯ

[image: postgreSQL]